# How to show glossary entry name in bold when using long style?

Tags: formatting, glossaries, bold

I am using the `glossaries` package in order to create a glossary. If I use:

```
\printglossary[type=main,style=list]
```

I get entry names in bold, but the layout won't be the one I wish. If I use:

```
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth}
\printglossary[type=main,style=long]
```

I will get the wanted layout exhibited, but the entry names won't be in bold. So, how to set the entry names to be shown in bold when using long style?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following is untested, but should work according to p. 167 of the `glossaries` manual:

```
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

Comment: I have tested this and can confirm that it works!