# Bold only \gls, not \glsdesc

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

How can I set `\gls` glossaries entries as bold, but not `\glsdesc` definitions?

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,style=listgroup]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apc} {
    name = {antigen presenting cell},
    description = {cells that present MHC proteins on their surface},
}

% glossary definitions as bold
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{\textbf{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\Glspl{apc} are \glsdesc*{apc}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

(Please note this is related, but not identical, to such question as [How to show glossary entry name in bold when using long style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13160/how-to-show-glossary-entry-name-in-bold-when-using-long-style))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line in your preamble:

```
\defglsentryfmt{\color{black}\bfseries\glsgenentryfmt}
```

and delete

```
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{\textbf{#1}}}
```

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,style=listgroup]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apc} {
    name = {antigen presenting cell},
    description = {cells that present MHC proteins on their surface},
}

% glossary definitions as bold
\defglsentryfmt{\color{black}\bfseries\glsgenentryfmt}

\begin{document}

\Glspl{apc} are \glsdesc*{apc}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I thought there would be no such direct approach to this one, thanks!

Comment: @RicardoCruz You're welcome

Comment: oh I just noticed this won't work for acronymous -- do you know if there is a solution for those?

Comment: @RicardoCruz Try adding `\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{\color{black}\bfseries\glsgenentryfmt}`

Comment: @RicardoCruz Happy about that!