# Formatting the "Description" section in a glossary (glossaries package)

Tags: formatting, glossaries, glossary

I am using the `glossaries` package in order to create a glossary. I want to change the **second** column (called "description") to appear in *italic*.

I searched in the web but I can't find the syntax of the command.
Trying to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13163) as

```
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[2]{\textit{#2}}
```

... doesn't work.

Neither can I find the name of the command (`\glsnamefont` should be the one for the name of the first entry) and `\glsdescriptionfont` or `\glslongfont` (just two attempts *g) doesn't work.

Comment: This will be doable, but there's not an equivalent macro to directly set the description font.  Which list style are you using?

Comment: I'm using:

\printglossary[style=long3colheader, type=main, title={Glossar}]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after a hard day with google myself:

I added the line:

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdescfont}{emph}
```

before the \printglossary - command.

So the working code is:

```
% ---------------------------------------------
% - Änderung des Headers und Erzeugen des Abkürzungsverzeichnisses
% - Fomatierung des Eintrages in kursiv
% ---------------------------------------------

\renewcommand*\entryname{Abk.} % Änderung des Namens der 1. Spalte 
\renewcommand*\descriptionname{Bedeutung} % Änderung des Namens der 2. Spalte 
\renewcommand*\pagelistname{Seite\\} % Änderung des Namens der 3. Spalte 
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdescfont}{emph}  % Formatierung der Spalte 'Bedeutung' in kursiv in beiden Verzeichnissen.

\printglossary[style=long3colheader, type=\acronymtype,title={Abkürzungen}] % Erstellen des Abkürzungsverzeichnisses  3 Spalten und Änderung des Titels.


% ---------------------------------------------
\newpage % \newpage just to demonstrate that links are correct
% ---------------------------------------------

% ---------------------------------------------
% - Änderung des Headers und Erzeugen des Glossars
% ---------------------------------------------

\renewcommand*\entryname{Begriff} % Änderung des Namens der 1. Spalte 
\renewcommand*\descriptionname{Bedeutung} % Änderung des Namens der 2. Spalte 
\renewcommand*\pagelistname{Seite\\} % Änderung des Namens der 3. Spalte 
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % Einträge der ersten Spalte werden fett

\printglossary[style=long3colheader, type=main, title={Glossar}] % Erstellen des Glossars mit 3 Spalten und Änderung des Titels.
% ---------------------------------------------
```

[image: The result:]

Thanks to all who tried to help me.